# 'Convective' Fourier number

Tags: dimensional-analysis, diffusion, convection

I'm working with a numerical solution to a 1D advection-diffusion equation for a multiphase problem, with convective exchange between the gas and solid phase. A non-dimensional parameter which comes out of this analysis has the following form:

$\frac{A h_c t}{m c_p}$

where $A$ is a surface area over which convective exchange occurs, and $h_c$ is the coefficient convective heat transfer ($t$ is the time scale, $m$ is mass, and $c_p$ is specific heat capacity).

To me, this looks similar to the Fourier number, but instead of a ratio of conduction to storage, it is a ratio of convection to storage. I could be missing something obvious, but is there a specific name for this form of non-dimensional number?

Answer (score 1):

This is the reciprocal of the time constant of the [lumped-capacitance model with convection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped-element_model) multiplied by the time. Broadly, the model assumes that the component interior remains at equilibrium, or equivalently that internal temperature variations are negligible, as often evaluated using the [Biot number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot_number).

Any reciprocal of a time constant multiplied by time will, of course, give a nondimensional number. In the absence of an eponym, "number of time constants" seems to be a suitable description.

Comment: Agreed. I'm just trying to write up my analysis and wondering if there is a widely accepted name (and symbol) which I can give this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't simplified the non-dimensional quantity to 'recognisable' form.

Notice that:

- $m=\rho V$ and the ratio $A/V \thicksim 1/L$, so the number is then $\frac{h_c T}{\rho c_p L}$
- Substituting a diffusional timescale $T \thicksim L^2/a$, the number becomes $\frac{h_c L}{ a \rho c_p}$
- By definition $a=\lambda / \rho c_p$ and the number becomes $\frac{h_c L}{ \lambda }$

This simplified form can be recognized as a Nusselt number (or Biot number).